# Проблема с кодом авторизации на сайте на PHP

Tags: php, php7, автоматизация

Вот код, пока в PHP плохо понимаю, только учусь.

```
<?PHP session_start(); ?>
<?PHP if(isset($_COOKIE['loggedIn']) && $_COOKIE['loggedIn']) : ?>
    <p>Hello, <?= $_COOKIE['login']; ?></p>
    <a href="<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>?logout=true">logout</a>
<?PHP else : ?>
    <form action="<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
        <label>login</label><input type="text" name="login" required><br>
        <label>password</label><input type="password" name="password" required><br>
        <label>email</label><input type="email" name="email" required><br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="login">
    </form>
<?PHP endif; ?>

<?PHP
$login = 'login';
$pass = 'pass';
$email = 'email@test.com';

if(isset($_POST['submit']) && !empty($_POST['submit'])) {
        $data['login'] = $_POST['login'] == $login ? $_POST['login'] : false;
        $data['pass'] = $_POST['password'] == $pass ? $_POST['password'] : false;
        $data['email'] = $_POST['email'] == $email ? $_POST['email'] : false;

        foreach($data as $key => $value) {
                If(!$value) $error[] = $key;
        }

        if(empty($error)) {
                setcookie('loggedIn', true);
                setcookie('PHPSESSID', session_id());
                setcookie('login', $data['login']);
                session_start();
                header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
        }
        else {
                print_r($error);
        }
}

if(Isset($_GET['logout']) && $_GET['logout'] == true) {
        setcookie("loggedIn", "false", time() - 3600);
        setcookie("PHPSESSID", "", time() - 3600);
        setcookie("login", "", time() - 3600);
        header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
        session_destroy();
}
?>
```

Выводит такие ошибки:

```
Warning: session_start(): Cannot start session when headers already sent in W:\domains\x.ru\index.php on line 3

 Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at W:\domains\x.ru\index.php:1) in W:\domains\x.ru\index.php on line 31

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at W:\domains\x.ru\index.php:1) in W:\domains\x.ru\index.php on line 32

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at W:\domains\x.ru\index.php:1) in W:\domains\x.ru\index.php on line 33

Warning: session_start(): Cannot start session when headers already sent in W:\domains\x.ru\index.php on line 34

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at W:\domains\x.ru\index.php:1) in W:\domains\x.ru\index.php on line 35
```

Что надо в коде исправить чтоб код работал правильно, за ранее благодарен.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`session_start()` и `header()` нужно использовать ДО того, как у вас на странице что-то выводится. Перед ними не может быть никакой html-разметки, ни какого-либо иного вывода. Кроме того кодировка файла должна быть без BOM (но сейчас почти все редакторы и IDE сохраняют в нормальной кодировке)

```
<?PHP session_start(); 

$login = 'login';
$pass = 'pass';
$email = 'email@test.com';

if($_GET['logout'] == true) {
    setcookie("loggedIn", "false", time() - 3600);
    setcookie("PHPSESSID", "", time() - 3600);
    setcookie("login", "", time() - 3600);
    header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
    session_destroy();
}

if($_POST['submit']) {
    $data['login'] = $_POST['login'] == $login ? $_POST['login'] : false;
    $data['pass'] = $_POST['password'] == $pass ? $_POST['password'] : false;
    $data['email'] = $_POST['email'] == $email ? $_POST['email'] : false;

    foreach($data as $key => $value) {
            If(!$value) $error[] = $key;
    }

    if(empty($error)) {
            setcookie('loggedIn', true);
            setcookie('PHPSESSID', session_id());
            setcookie('login', $data['login']);
            session_start();
            header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
    }
    else {
            print_r($error);
    }
}

if($_COOKIE['loggedIn']) : ?>
<p>Hello, <?= $_COOKIE['login']; ?></p>
<a href="<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>?logout=true">logout</a>
<?PHP else : ?>
<form action="<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
    <label>login</label><input type="text" name="login" required><br>
    <label>password</label><input type="password" name="password" required><br>
    <label>email</label><input type="email" name="email" required><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="login">
</form>
<?PHP endif; ?>
```

Comment: ОК напишите пожалуйста ваш вариант кода, что я понял почему не работает.

Comment: добавил к ответу

Comment: Добавлять код бессмысленно, поскольку проблема не в нем.

Comment: так я и не добавлял код, я просто переставил блоки снизу вверх и убрал лишние проверки в if

Comment: переставлять блоки снизу вверх *тоже* бессмысленно

Comment: `добавил к ответу – The Drote 6 минут назад"`... `я не добавлял код – The Drote 2 минуты назад`. Люблю последовательность в поступках

Comment: все равно спасибо за вашу работу, сейчас работает.

Comment: Раз переставлять блоки в данном случае бессмысленно, товарищ Ипатьев, рекомендую вам открыть мануал по PHP и впредь не писать подобных бессмысленных комментариев.